# JQuery: Want to refactor some Jquery code to make it simple and easy

Tags: jquery, refactoring, jquery-post

I have the following code in JQuery, On DOM Ready it runs, its job is to post data to my PHP file, and return the returned data into the specified div. I am using 5 bits of code, most of it is repeating it self over again. I wanted to refactor this somehow, can someone make this code into a couple of lines is possible?

Basically, on change of a select box element, it runs and does the code.

```
// First Level Categories
    $("#slct_firstCat").live("change", function(){
    $("#div_secondCat").fadeOut();
    $("#div_thirdCat").fadeOut();
    $("#div_fourthCat").fadeOut();
    $("#successCats").remove();

    var actionRequested = "AJAX_getCats";
    var url = "index.php";
    var catId = $("#slct_firstCat").val();

    $.post(url, {AJAX_Action: actionRequested, categoryId: catId, categoryLevel: 1},
        function(data){
            $("#div_secondCat").fadeIn().html(data);
           });
    // End of Function getCats
    });

// Second Level Categories
    $("#slct_secondCat").live("change", function(){
    $("#div_thirdCat").fadeOut();
    $("#div_fourthCat").fadeOut();
    $("#successCats").remove();

    var actionRequested = "AJAX_getCats";
    var url = "index.php";
    var catId = $("#slct_secondCat").val();

    $.post(url, {AJAX_Action: actionRequested, categoryId: catId, categoryLevel: 2},
        function(data){
            $("#div_thirdCat").fadeIn().html(data);
           });
    // End of Function getCats
    });


// Third Level Categories
    $("#slct_thirdCat").live("change", function(){
    $("#div_fourthCat").fadeOut();
    $("#successCats").remove();

    var actionRequested = "AJAX_getCats";
    var url = "index.php";
    var catId = $("#slct_thirdCat").val();

    $.post(url, {AJAX_Action: actionRequested, categoryId: catId, categoryLevel: 3},
        function(data){
            $("#div_fourthCat").fadeIn().html(data);
           });
    // End of Function getCats
    });

// Fourth Level Categories
    $("#slct_fourthCat").live("change", function(){
    $("#successCats").remove();

    var actionRequested = "AJAX_getCats";
    var url = "index.php";
    var catId = $("#slct_fourthCat").val();

    $.post(url, {AJAX_Action: actionRequested, categoryId: catId, categoryLevel: 4},
        function(data){
            $("#div_fourthCat").fadeIn().html(data);
           });
    // End of Function getCats
    });

// Fifth Level Categories
    $("#slct_fifthCat").live("change", function(){
    $("#successCats").remove();
    var actionRequested = "AJAX_getCats";
    var url = "index.php";
    var catId = $("#slct_fifthCat").val();

    $.post(url, {AJAX_Action: actionRequested, categoryId: catId, categoryLevel: 5},
        function(data){
            $("#div_fourthCat").fadeIn().html(data);
           });
    // End of Function getCats
    });
```

You can see most the code is repeated many times, the only things that change are the element names and the category level in the post action.

I hate having this huge chunk of code in my JS script, used over and over again, surely someone out-there can help reduce this to a few lines or a function if possible?

**--------------------------- EDIT ---------------------------**

This is the php code that sends the data back from the $.post, if this helps.
Each select box is inside its own div when posted to html, The DIVs are on the html and not ajax'd in.
Basically, I want to navigate down to a category using these select box's to easily visualize where I am in the category nav. The $data variable, is an object which has an array of the category data requested.
(Sorry Im pressed for time g2g work, else I would have cleaned up the code more)

```
<?php if (isset($data->CategoryArray->Category->LeafCategory) == 1){ ?>

    <div id='successCats' align='center'>
    <b>Your Selected Category is:</b><br/>
    <select id='selectedCategory' name='selectedCategory' size='1'>
    <option value='<?=$data->CategoryArray->Category->CategoryID."'>".$data->CategoryArray->Category->CategoryName;?></option>
    </select>
    </div>

<?php } else {  ?>
<?php
$catLevel = $_POST['categoryLevel'];
if ($catLevel == 1){
    echo "<select id=\"slct_secondCat\" name=\"slct_secondCat\" size=\"15\">";
} elseif ($catLevel == 2) {
    echo "<select id=\"slct_thirdCat\" name=\"slct_thirdCat\" size=\"15\">";
}
  else if($catLevel == 3){
  echo "<select id=\"slct_fourthCat\" name=\"slct_fourthCat\" size=\"15\">";
} else if($catLevel == 4){
  echo "<select id=\"slct_fifthCat\" name=\"slct_fifthCat\" size=\"15\">";
}

    $cats = array_slice($data->CategoryArray->Category,1);
    foreach ($cats as $cats){
    if ($cats->CategoryID == $cats->CategoryParentID){
    // Do Nothing - Get rid of the first header Cat
    } else {
    $option =  "<option value=\"" . $cats->CategoryID . "\">" . $cats->CategoryName;
    if(!isset($cats->LeafCategory)){
        $option .= " >";
    }

    $option .= "</option>";

    echo $option;
    }
    } // End of For each

} // End of First If Else
?>
<?php echo "</select>"; ?>
```

Comment: Should probably be on CodeReview http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I just signed up, great site, I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But it looks like this block just needs to be turned into a function

```
function LevelCategories(levelSelector, levelSelector2) {
    $("#slct_secondCat").live("change", function(){
    $("#div_thirdCat").fadeOut();
    $("#div_fourthCat").fadeOut();
    $("#successCats").remove();

    var actionRequested = "AJAX_getCats";
    var url = "index.php";
    var catId = $(levelSelector).val();

    $.post(url, {AJAX_Action: actionRequested, categoryId: catId, categoryLevel: 2},
        function(data){
            $(levelSelector2).fadeIn().html(data);
           });
    // End of Function getCats
    });
}
```

Then just call the function with the correct selectors (I may have those wrong...

```
LevelCategories("#slct_firstCat", "#slct_secondCat");
LevelCategories("#slct_secondCat", "#slct_thirdCat");
LevelCategories("#slct_thirdCat", "#slct_fourthCat");
LevelCategories("#slct_fourthCat", "#slct_fourthCat");
LevelCategories("#slct_fifthCat", "#slct_fourthCat");
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking, but im having trouble attaching this to a event in html, I was using onchange="LevelCategories(..." but it didnt work with the "#" symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Start small, do some refactoring, test to verify the functionality is the same, iterate. The simplest refactoring would be to do this:

```
function loadCategories($container, catId, level) {
    var actionRequested = "AJAX_getCats", url = "index.php";

    $.post(url, {AJAX_Action: actionRequested, categoryId: catId, categoryLevel: level},
        function(data){
            $container.fadeIn().html(data);
    }); 
}

// First Level Categories
    $("#slct_firstCat").live("change", function(){
    $("#div_secondCat").fadeOut();
    $("#div_thirdCat").fadeOut();
    $("#div_fourthCat").fadeOut();
    $("#successCats").remove();

    var catId = $("#slct_firstCat").val();
    loadCategories($("#div_secondCat"), catId, 1);  
    // End of Function getCats
    });

// Second Level Categories
    $("#slct_secondCat").live("change", function(){
    $("#div_thirdCat").fadeOut();
    $("#div_fourthCat").fadeOut();
    $("#successCats").remove();

    var catId = $("#slct_secondCat").val();
    loadCategories($("#div_thirdCat"), catId, 2);   
    // End of Function getCats
    });


// Third Level Categories
    $("#slct_thirdCat").live("change", function(){
    $("#div_fourthCat").fadeOut();
    $("#successCats").remove();

    var catId = $("#slct_thirdCat").val();
    loadCategories($("#div_fourthCat"), catId, 3);  
    // End of Function getCats
    });

// Fourth Level Categories
    $("#slct_fourthCat").live("change", function(){
    $("#successCats").remove();

    var catId = $("#slct_fourthCat").val();
    loadCategories($("#div_fourthCat"), catId, 4);             
    // End of Function getCats
    });

// Fifth Level Categories
    $("#slct_fifthCat").live("change", function(){
    $("#successCats").remove();

    var catId = $("#slct_fifthCat").val();
    loadCategories($("#div_fourthCat"), catId, 5);
    // End of Function getCats
    });
```

Of course this is far from perfect - my point here is you should learn to do it yourself, step by step.

Edit: Second pass and I did my best to keep the same functionality. The code is NOT tested:)

```
function loadCategories($container, catId, level) {
    var actionRequested = "AJAX_getCats", url = "index.php";

    $.post(url, {AJAX_Action: actionRequested, categoryId: catId, categoryLevel: level},
        function(data){
            $container.fadeIn().html(data);
    }); 
}

var catSelects = [
        $("#slct_firstCat"),
        $("#slct_secondCat"),
        $("#slct_thirdCat"),
        $("#slct_fourthCat"),
        $("#slct_fifthCat")
];

var catDivs = [
        $(),
        $("#div_secondCat"),
        $("#div_thirdCat"),
        $("#div_fourthCat"),
];      

function attachChangeEvents() {
    $.each(catSelects, function(index) {
        var catIndex = index;
        this.live("change", function () {
            // Fade out other divs
            $.each(catDivs, function (divIndex) {
                if(divIndex > catIndex) {
                    catDivs[divIndex].fadeOut();
                }
            });

            $("#successCats").remove();         

            var nextLevel = catIndex+1,
            nextDiv = catDivs[Math.min(nextLevel, catDivs.length-1)];

            loadCategories(nextDiv, this.val(), nextLevel);                 
        });
    };          
};
```

Comment: I understand the first example, but im not sure how I would exactly use the second example, I have a select box, but am having trouble attributing a event script onchange of the select box, how would I use the second example?

Comment: I assumed the entire code you posted ran at once and the selects were available at this time. I am starting to get the impression this is not the case. If you can provide some more details, e.g. what elements are present and when do you execute the five pieces of code, I can modify the example and explain it better.